# Combine two tables in one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in MSSQL Server 2012 and would like to combine them into one new table. They are linked by the column messageID. The first table (*Message*) has

```
messageID
sender
date
```

The second table(*recipientInfo*) has

```
messageID
recipient
```

The main problem is that in *Message* the messageID is the primary key and thus unique. In *recipientInfo* the messageID is not unique (because one message can have multiple recipients). I'd like to have a new table with either

- One row per message, with recipients concatenated in one column
- Multiple rows per message, when there are multiple recipients (one recipient per row)

Comment: Do you want to create a view and leave the existing tables there? Or do you want to combine the two tables permanently?

Comment: @Ste I'd like a new table, so a permanent combination

Comment: @casperOne in what way is this not a real question? I got a perfectly good answer to it as well, that I accepted. Whats your problem?

Comment: @Freek8 The problem is yours; questions on Stack Overflow are expected to show research effort, which you have not done.  I *strongly* recommend reading [Stack Overflow is not Your Personal Research Assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140951) for a better understanding as to why this question fails to meet the quality standards of the site.

Comment: @casperOne I don't see the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this (if you are using MSSQL 2005+):

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable
(
    messageID INT,
    sender VARCHAR(100),
    recipient VARCHAR(MAX),
    date DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO NewTable(messageID,sender,recipient,date)
SELECT
    [Message].messageID,
    [Message].sender,
    STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT 
                ',' +recipient
            FROM
                recipientInfo
            WHERE
                recipientInfo.messageID=[Message].messageID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,1,'') AS recipient,
    [Message].date
FROM
    [Message]
```

Comment: +1 For Xml Path is best solution to pivot and concatenate values

Comment: @Arion Thanks, this worked like a charm. And really quick too!

Comment: @Arion since i'm also trying to learn something, what does FOR XML PATH do?

Comment: @Freek8 : it is concating the values as xml. Then the stuff makes it a varchar. If you are interested then read http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a view and leave the existing tables there? Or do you want to combine the two tables permanently?

```
SELECT m.messageID, m.sender, m.date, r.recipient
INTO New_Table
FROM Message m LEFT OUTER JOIN
recipientinfo r on m.messageID = r.messageID
```

Comment: Yes, but you barely gave me thirty seconds to delete the comment and revise my answer.

Comment: thank you, this one works too. Since Arion's solution takes up less space im going to go with that one

Answer (score 0):

```
select msg.messageID, msg.sender, rep.recipient, msg.date 
from Message msg 
left outer join recipientInfo rep on msg.messageID = rep.messageID
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to sort the spellings out here

```
  select sender,date,( select recipient+chr(10) from receipientInfo as r where r.messageid = m.messageid order by r.recipient FOR XML PATH ('')) as receipents from message as m
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just merge the two tables

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

this might be something more suited and there are more ways than one to do it