# Joining cells together to shorten result in sql

Tags: t-sql, select, concatenation

Let's say my select statement in t-sql returns

```
John Smith | Chicago | a  
John Smith | Chicago | f  
John Smith | Chicago | j  
Josh Dude  | Houston | p  
Josh Dude  | Houston | s
```

And I want it to return

```
John Smith | Chicago | a, f, j  
Josh Dude  | Houston | p, s
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql PIVOT and string concatenation aggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783680/sql-pivot-and-string-concatenation-aggregate)

Comment: Did you try anything to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first half of the article [T-SQL:  Normalized data to a single comma delineated string and back](https://rdsrc.us/NOAwjx) is a code and image-heavy tutorial on how you can use STUFF and a FOR XML PATH statement take a normalized set and turn one column into a single comma separated value.

Good luck.