# Amazon Redshift Pivot using Concatenation

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which looks like

```
|------|-------|---------|
|foo_id|country|foo_value|
|------|-------|---------|
|  1   |   US  |   abc   |
|------|-------|---------|
|  1   |   IN  |   def   |
|------|-------|---------|
|  1   |   DE  |   abc   |
|------|-------|---------|
|  2   |   US  |   xyz   |
|------|-------|---------|
|  2   |   IN  |   klm   |
|------|-------|---------|
```

Here the combination of foo_id and country is unique. So there will be only 1 row for 1 and US.

I want to pivot it as

```
|------|--------|---------|---------|
|foo_id|   US   |   IN    |    DE   | 
|------|--------|---------|---------|
|  1   |   abc  |   def   |    abc  |
|------|--------|---------|---------|
|  2   |   xyz  |   klm   |         |
|------|--------|---------|---------|
```

I googled for this question and I found the answer for SQL Server and it uses "for XML".

[Sql PIVOT and string concatenation aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783680/sql-pivot-and-string-concatenation-aggregate)

This answer is using "FOR XML" but I'm not sure why I should use "FOR XML" when I'm not dealing with XML at all. Is there a better answer which is pure ANSI SQL or perhaps better suited for redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    foo_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN foo_value END) AS US,
    MAX(CASE WHEN country = 'IN' THEN foo_value END) AS "IN",
    MAX(CASE WHEN country = 'DE' THEN foo_value END) AS DE
FROM mytable
GROUP BY foo_id
```

Comment: Thanks. do you know how to escape IN? it seems its also a clause in SQL. I tried `'IN'` but that doesn't work

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch: my bad, should be `"IN"`.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I try to do a group by I get error `Invalid operation: failed to find conversion function from "unknown" to character varying`