# Pivot table Non-unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have two tables that I want to join together into 1 row by accessruleId for an ssrs report.  The issue is FieldName has dynamic values and the same fieldName could appear more than once  It seems like Pivot table is what I want but examples I've looked at is pivoting off a unique value and doing an aggregate function.  Below is the output for query 1 and 2 and I want to combine the results so it looks like screenshot 3. If a given fieldname shows up more than once (businessArea in this case) I want to make the values comma delimited. Any links to examples similar to my need would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using sql server 2016

Query 1

```
select ar.AccessRuleId, ar.EffectiveDate, ar.TermDate, ar.CreatedByUser, ar.LastUpdatedUser
from [AccessRule].[AccessRule] ar
where ar.AccessRuleId = 1
```

Query 2

```
select rf.FieldName, ro.[Value]
from [AccessRule].[RuleOperation] ro
join [AccessRule].[RuleField] rf on ro.FieldId = rf.RuleFieldId
where ro.AccessRuleId = 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide your queries as text and data as tabular text. We cannot make an efficient use of pictures.

Comment: Is this similar to the question @ https://stackoverflow.com/q/14783680/461822

Comment: Yes it does!  I will take a look. Thanks