# Pivot/transpond source table to new view and concat rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, concatenation

I can't figure out the statement to get from `SourceTable` to the `NewViewResult`.

Currently the source is still on a Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

[Description of Source and expected result](https://ibb.co/cxWxftk)

Below is the code to create and fill the `SourceTable`:

```
CREATE TABLE SourceTable
(
    [Contract] [nvarchar] (255) NULL,
    [Role] [nvarchar] (255) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar] (255) NULL
);

INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('First Contract', 'Author', 'Tom');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('First Contract', 'Manager', 'Ben');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('First Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Kate');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('First Contract', 'Signee', 'John');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('First Contract', 'Singee 2', 'Eli');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Author', 'Chris');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Manager', 'Susan');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Davis');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Tomi');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Jane');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Dolly');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Ray');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Pat');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Reviewer', 'Amy');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Signee', 'Eli');
INSERT INTO [SourceTable] ([Contract], [Role], [Name]) 
VALUES ('Another Contract', 'Signee 2', 'John');
```

[image: Source Table to new View]

Comment: Any chance you'd be willing to either upgrade your SQLS or install this: https://github.com/orlando-colamatteo/ms-sql-server-group-concat-sqlclr

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this by conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  contract,
  MAX(CASE WHEN role = 'Author' Then Name End) as Author,
  MAX(CASE WHEN role = 'Manager' Then Name End) as Manager,
  ...
FROM t
GROUP BY contract
```

But the slight sticking point is the multiple names. On a more modern SQLS or one upgraded with a CLR group concat you could swap the MAX for GROUP_CONCAT

If you're sticking with your vanilla SQLS2012 you'll probably end up with a STUFF/FOR XML PATH hack on a coordinated subquery

```
MAX(STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Name 
FROM t t1 WHERE t.contract = t1.contract
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' )) as reviewers,
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Caius. I'll check this as well.

It seems I did not search good enough in the first place. I have found a possible solution here: [Sql PIVOT and string concatenation aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783680/sql-pivot-and-string-concatenation-aggregate)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT Contract, 
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Role = 'Author' THEN Name END, ',') Author,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Role = 'Manager' THEN Name END, ',') Manager,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Role = 'Reviewer' THEN Name END, ',') Reviewer,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Role = 'Signee' THEN Name END, ',') Signee,
       STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Role = 'Signee 2' THEN Name END, ',') [Singee 2]
FROM SourceTable
GROUP BY Contract
ORDER BY Contract DESC;
```

Returns:

```
+------------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+
|     Contract     | Author | Manager |             Reviewer              | Signee | Singee 2 |
+------------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+
| First Contract   | Tom    | Ben     | Kate                              | John   | Eli      |
| Another Contract | Chris  | Susan   | Davis,Tomi,Jane,Dolly,Ray,Pat,Amy | Eli    | John     |
+------------------+--------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------+
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39ed41de63a72d089a2b63497149abc6)